# How do I install the latest version of Prometheus on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I'm having trouble installing the latest version of Prometheus on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. All the guides that I can find are for 14.04 and the move from systemV to systemd makes these guides incompatible (or at least incomplete) when setting it up on 16.04.

I can install Prometheus from apt, but it installs version 0.16.2 and the current version is 1.0.2.

I've been using the official [prometheus.io install guide](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/install/) and [this guide on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-prometheus-to-monitor-your-ubuntu-14-04-server).

Can anyone help me with the systemd setup? I'm relatively experienced with Ubuntu, but the systemd change is throwing me a curve ball.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following unit file worked for me when installing the prometheus *server* version 1.x (as opposed to an exporter).

```
# /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus Server
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=prometheus
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus-1.1.2.linux-amd64/prometheus \
                                -config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
                                -storage.local.path=/var/lib/prometheus/data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This assumes, of course, that you've created a prometheus user and granted necessary permissions.

Then use the commands mentioned by WInfly.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable prometheus
$ sudo systemctl start prometheus
$ sudo systemctl status prometheus
```

I have found the following helpful:

Prometheus: https://blog.svedr.in/posts/prometheus-quick-start.html

Man pages for unit file directives: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html

Comment: This prometheus syntax is valid for version 1.x.

Answer (score 4):

The server storage argument name changed in version 2.x, working syntax:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus Server
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus-2.2.1.linux-amd64/prometheus \
                                --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
                                --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus/data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer in [this article](https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-use-prometheus-to-monitor-your-centos-7-server/). The specific part that I was missing in trying to set this up to run with systemd was creating the unit file. Below is creating the unit file for node_exporter and then running it as a service. Hope this helps someone else!

**Create the unit file:**

```
$ sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service
[Unit]
Description=Node Exporter

[Service]
User=vxx
ExecStart=/home/vxx/Prometheus/node_exporter/node_exporter

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**Then start the service after reloading daemon or reboot the server:**

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable node_exporter.service
$ sudo systemctl start node_exporter.service
$ sudo systemctl status node_exporter.service
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still coming back to this question, I've scriptified the installation of prometheus, node_exporter, and apache_exporter based on [this DigitalOcean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-prometheus-on-ubuntu-16-04).

You can find my scripts here:
https://github.com/icolwell/install_scripts

The following scripts may be of interest:

```
prometheus_install.bash
prometheus_node_exporter_install.bash
prometheus_apache_exporter_install.bash
```

You can download and run the scripts using the following:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/icolwell/install_scripts/master/prometheus_install.bash
bash prometheus_install.bash
```

Note that any existing prometheus configuration will be overridden.